# How to loop to ask question again using if-else statements python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, repeat

I'm trying to make my program run where if someone gets the question wrong (i.e. the user enters a number to large or too little that it will ask the user to input an Answer again. I've tried using While True: loops, but that makes my program have an infinite loop that never ends. Any help would be appreciated

```
import random

def main() :
    # Generate two random numbers between 1 and 100
    n1 = random.randint(1,100)
    n2 = random.randint(1,100)

    # Ask the answer
    print("What is the sum:",n1,"+",n2)
    attempt = 1
    answer = int(input("Answer: "))


    if answer != n1 + n2 and answer < n1 + n2:
        print("Wrong! The correct answer is greater than " + str(answer) + ".")
    else:
        if answer != n1 + n2 and answer > n1 + n2:
            print("Wrong! The correct answer is less than " + str(answer) + ".")
        else:
            if answer == n1 + n2:
                print("Yes! The correct answer is " + str(answer) + "." + "\n You got it in " + str(attempt) + " attempts.") 
                exit()

main()
```

Comment: Try `while answer != n1 + n2`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work with multiple incorrect answers, and not get stuck in an endless loop. Anyhow, here you go:

```
def main():
    # Generate two random numbers between 1 and 100
    n1 = random.randint(1,100)
    n2 = random.randint(1,100)
    attempt = 1
    # Ask the answer
    print("What is the sum:",n1,"+",n2)

    while True:
        answer = int(input("Answer: "))
        if answer < n1 + n2:
            print("Wrong! The correct answer is greater than " + str(answer) + ".")
            attempt += 1
            continue
        elif answer > n1 + n2:
            print("Wrong! The correct answer is less than " + str(answer) + ".")
            attempt += 1
            continue
        elif answer == n1 + n2:
            print("Yes! The correct answer is " + str(answer) + "." + "\n You got it in " + str(attempt) + " attempts.")
            break

main()
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

We can shorten the code quite a bit... I also added comments as explanation.

```py
import random

def main() :
    # Generate two random numbers between 1 and 100
    n1 = random.randint(1,100)
    n2 = random.randint(1,100)

    # Ask the answer
    print("What is the sum:",n1,"+",n2)
    attempt = 1
    answer = int(input("Answer: "))

    # keep looping until the answer is correct
    while answer != n1 + n2:
        # we already checked in the while loop that answer isn't == to n1+n2, so we don't need to check again
        if answer < n1 + n2:
            print("Wrong! The correct answer is greater than " + str(answer) + ".")
        # if answer != n1+n2 and answer is not < n1 + n2, it can only be answer > n1 + n2 so we don't need to explicitly state it 
        else:
            print("Wrong! The correct answer is less than " + str(answer) + ".")
        # increase the attempt number
        attempt += 1
        # ask the user again for an input
        answer = int(input("Answer: "))
    # once the while loop is done (when answer is == n1 + n2) then run this code below
    print("Yes! The correct answer is " + str(answer) + "." + "\n You got it in " + str(attempt) + " attempts.") 
    exit()
main()
```

Without my comments:

```py
import random

def main() :
    # Generate two random numbers between 1 and 100
    n1 = random.randint(1,100)
    n2 = random.randint(1,100)

    # Ask the answer
    print("What is the sum:",n1,"+",n2)
    attempt = 1
    answer = int(input("Answer: "))

    while answer != n1 + n2:
        if answer < n1 + n2:
            print("Wrong! The correct answer is greater than " + str(answer) + ".")
        else:
            print("Wrong! The correct answer is less than " + str(answer) + ".")
        attempt += 1
        answer = int(input("Answer: "))
    print("Yes! The correct answer is " + str(answer) + "." + "\n You got it in " + str(attempt) + " attempts.") 
    exit()
main()
```